# How to Join Two data sets for Google area chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

My server side code returns a json formatted response which I need to show on google area chart. Looks like this.

```
investment":
    [
        {
            "date":"2015-04-08",
            "amount":"110.00"
        },
        {
            "date":"2015-04-09",
            "amount":"100.00"
        }
    ],
"revenue":
    [
        {
            "amount":"60",
            "date":"2015-03-23"
        },
        {
            "amount":"250.5",
            "date":"2015-04-08"
        },

        {
            "date":"2015-04-09",
            "amount":"110.00"
        }
    ]
```

I am trying to achieve an array which will look like this.

```
[
    ["Date", "Investment", "Revenue"],
    ["2015-04-08", 0, 100.00],
    ["2015-04-18", 150.3, 50.00],
    ["2015-04-28", 40, ]
    ....
]
```

**In words:**

1. If it both data sets have data for same dates. They goes in to single array.
2. If a dataset do not have value for a date. It will have zero.

So far I came up with the code below. Which is not what I want. There will be duplicate dates with one value always null.

```
var dataAreaChart = [["Date", "Investment", "Revenue"]];

if (data.investment != undefined && data.investment.length > 0) {
   for (var i = 0; i < data.investment.length; i++) {
       dataAreaChart.push([data.investment[i].date,  parseFloat(data.investment[i].amount), null]);
   }
}

if (data.revenue != undefined && data.revenue.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.revenue.length; i++) {
        dataAreaChart.push([data.revenue[i].date, null, parseFloat(data.revenue[i].amount)]);
    }
}
```

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if it can be done directly with the data in the given structure.

So, what you can do is, iterate through the 'investment' and 'revenue' arrays and create a intermediate structure of the data, from which you can generate the desired output structure.

I am assuming that the dates will be unique with-in the respective arrays.

You can create a new object with the date as key and the `investment` and `revenue` as its properties.

```
var entries = {}

if (data.investment != undefined && data.investment.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.investment.length; i++) {
        entries[data.investment[i].date] = {'investment' : parseFloat(data.investment[i].amount), 'revenue' : 0 };
    }
}

if (data.revenue != undefined && data.revenue.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.revenue.length; i++) {
        if (entries.hasOwnProperty(data.revenue[i].date)) {
            entries[data.revenue[i].date].revenue = parseFloat(data.revenue[i].amount);
         } else {
            entries[data.revenue[i].date] = {'revenue' : parseFloat(data.revenue[i].amount), 'investment' : 0 };
        }
    }

}
```

Now from this `entries` object we can generate the array structure.

```
var dataAreaChart = [["Date", "Investment", "Revenue"]];
for (entry in entries) {
    dataAreaChart.push([entry, entries[entry].investment, entries[entry].revenue])
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will look at it when back to work. Out of office now :)